# Vector registers in rust inline asm: Cannot use value of type `Simd<i64, 8>` for inline assembly

Tags: assembly, rust, inline-assembly

Compiling the following inline assembly:

```
#![feature(portable_simd)]

use std::simd::{i64x8, f64x8};
use std::arch::asm;


pub fn convert(a: i64x8) -> f64x8{
    let converted: f64x8;
    unsafe {
        asm!(
        "vcvtqq2pd {converted} {a}",
        a = in(zmm_reg) a,
        converted = out(zmm_reg) converted,
        );
    }
    converted
}
```

Leads to the errors:

```
error: cannot use value of type `Simd<i64, 8>` for inline assembly
  --> <source>:12:25
   |
12 |         a = in(zmm_reg) a,
   |                         ^
   |
   = note: only integers, floats, SIMD vectors, pointers and function pointers can be used as arguments for inline assembly

error: cannot use value of type `Simd<f64, 8>` for inline assembly
  --> <source>:13:34
   |
13 |         converted = out(zmm_reg) converted,
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: only integers, floats, SIMD vectors, pointers and function pointers can be used as arguments for inline assembly

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

You will need `-C target-feature=+avx512f` to compile the above. Alternatively see [this godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Pd7361caq)

This doesn't make a ton of sense to me because the [inline assembly docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/inline-assembly.html) clearly state that `f64x8` and `i64x8` are acceptable input types for `zmm_reg`.

Additionally the error message states that SIMD vectors are acceptable, but thats what I'm inputting.

If its relevant this reproduces on:

```
active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.68.0-nightly (afaf3e07a 2023-01-14)
```

Is this a rust bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which version of the Rust toolchain are you programming for?

Comment: Most recent nightly.

Comment: Oh and x86_64 linux on zen4 if it matters

Comment: Can you provide the exact nightly version?  I am not a Rust expert, but this smells like it may be related to a toolchain issue.  Tomorrow, the most recently nightly version is a different one, so who knows which one it is that you really use?

Comment: This is reproducible on [godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/5qEbh85oG) which is on nightly `0b90256ad 2023-01-13`

Comment: [I looked at the compiler implementation](https://cs.github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9e75dddf609c0201d03f9792e850f95d6a283d11/compiler/rustc_hir_analysis/src/check/intrinsicck.rs#L82), and it only checks for scalar types, not arrays like `std::simd::Simd` is defined. So this looks like a compiler bug to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the compiler doesn't yet support using portable simd types in assembly ([relevant issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/106924)). Note that not all portable simd types can be sent to assembly, things like using an `f64x16` type is perfectly legal, but I do not know of any supported architecture that could handle the equivalent type. As a workaround, use the platform specific vector types, such as [`__m512i`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86_64/struct.__m512i.html) or [`__m512d`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86_64/struct.__m512f.html).

```
#![feature(portable_simd)]
#![feature(stdsimd)]

use std::simd::{i64x8, f64x8};
use std::arch::asm;
use std::arch::x86_64::*;

pub fn convert(a: i64x8) -> f64x8{
    let a = __mm512i::from(a);
    let converted: __mm512d;
    unsafe {
        asm!(
        "vcvtqq2pd {converted}, {a}",
        a = in(zmm_reg) a,
        converted = out(zmm_reg) converted,
        );
    }
    converted.into()
}
```

[Godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/vzznoY18c)

Of course, if you're doing that, try to write your code with the appropriate simd intrinsics instead of assembly if possible, to help enable the compiler to optimize your code.